# Change a default font in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I know you can change the default font in Outlook for sending messages using 'Options' and by changing **normalemail.dotm**, but none of those methods work for my case.

For demonstration purposes, the following VBA code can be found on the Microsoft web site. [Application.CreateItem method (Outlook)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitem)

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail()   
 'Creates a new email item and modifies its properties      
 Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem           
 'Create email item      
 Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)      
 With objMail      
 'Set body format to HTML      
 .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML      
 .HTMLBody = "<HTML><H2>The body of this message will appear in HTML.</H2><BODY> Please enter the message text here. </BODY></HTML>"      
 .Display      
 End With      
End Sub
```

We are not using VBA, but calling the same Office methods from C#. The problem is the same in any case as the font for the new message varies from user to user. In my experience, some see Times Roman; others see Calibri.

I know we could hard code the font into the html body, but we really want to leave font selection to Outlook and the end user. We are just not able to instruct them how to change the font.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with code. If you want to set default font for all users, we can also deploy related registry key (Mail Settings) via GPO.

Font settings are saved in this path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Common\MailSettings

This was discussed in this Technet thread:

[Set a standard font for Outlook through group policy](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0a72088-b7d5-4acf-b16b-1d2207bfcb50/set-a-standard-font-for-outlook-through-group-policy?forum=outlook)

[Outlook 2013 Ariel default font registry keys](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7b82cb01-0a52-4266-8c3f-7f11159db873/outlook-2013-ariel-default-font-registry-keys?forum=outlook)